# Variable passed to directive becomes undefined at parent?

Tags: angularjs

I have following code:

parent.jade:

```
chat-box(message-content="messageContent" send-message="sendMessage()")
div {{messageContent}}
```

parent.js:

```
$scope.messageContent;
$scope.sendMessage = function(){
    alert($scope.messageContent);
}
```

directive.js:

```
app.directive('chatBox', ['$window', function ($window) {
    //---
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            messageContent: '=',
            sendMessage: '&?'
        },
        templateUrl: '/tpl/chatbox',
        link: function(scope, element, attr){

        }
    };
    //---
}]);
```

directive.jade:

```
div(layout="row" layout-align="bottom bottom" style="padding: 10px; flex-shrink: 0;")
    textarea(ng-model="messageContent" flex)
    md-button(ng-click="sendMessage()")
```

It will always alert me with `undefined` for `$scope.messageContent`, but if I try to use `ng-change` at `textarea` and calls the function inside my directive, it will return me the correct value.

It also prints the correct value for div at parent.

Anyone has idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by changing `$scope.messageContent;` to `$scope.messageContent = {};` in parent controller.